# How to get records at top with availablity in all sizes using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table that has product sizes with stock.
I want `product_id`s that are available in all sizes to be listed at the top, and then everything else should be listed below that.

My table:

```
Id product_id  product_name   size   stock
1      1            XYZ         S      2
2      1            XYZ         M      0
3      1            XYZ         L      3
8      1            XYZ         XL     3
----------------------------------------------------
4      2            ABC         S      1
5      2            ABC         M      1
6      2            ABC         L      1
```

I have 2 Products: `ABC` and `XYZ`.
You see that for the product `ABC`, stock is available in all 3 sizes (S, M, L), but the product `XYZ` has only 2 sizes available (S, L).
I want the product `ABC` to move to the top of the list, while the rest moves down.

My Expected output is:

```
product_id   product_name
   2             ABC
   1             XYZ
```

I have tried this query so far:

```
select product_id, product_name from product_attributes group by product_id
```

Note :- the number of size values can increase (e.g. XL) but I want to check only these sizes (S,M,L)

Comment: Is it fix, that there are always 3 different Sitzes for each Product id?

Comment: What was the result of what you tried?  How did that differ from what you expected?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff no it can be more also

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

You can determine which products have *all* sizes available by comparing the total number of rows for a product (`COUNT(*)`) with those rows with `stock` > 0 (`SUM(stock > 0)`). In MySQL we can treat that comparison as an integer and use it in an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM product_attributes
WHERE size in ('S', 'M', 'L')
GROUP BY product_id, product_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) = SUM(stock > 0) DESC
```

Output:

```
product_id  product_name
2           ABC
1           XYZ
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3312dc77efe1796f9f0986c61cd64853)

Comment: see my updated question..  i want to check with theses sizes only  S,M,L  but new size can also come

Comment: @user see my updated query and demo. It includes size `XL` as well to show the query working

Answer (score 0):

> I want the product ABC to move to the top of the list, while the rest moves down.

and

> Note :- Yes size can be increase but i want to check with only these sizes (S,M,L)

you can use `order by count(case when stock <> 0 then 1 end)`  + `where size in ('S','M','L')`

```
select product_id, product_name 
from product_attributes 
where size in ('S','M','L')
group by product_id,product_name
order by count(case when stock <> 0 then 1 end) desc
```

[Demo Link MySQL 8.0 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bfc7997f35fb085457b5e4cc65e557e3)

Comment: This will only work properly if all products have the same number of sizes. Otherwise a product with 3 of 4 sizes would rank higher than a product with 2 of 2 sizes.

Comment: @Nick Thanks, but as I understand it, order by stock > 0 size count that’s what op wants?

Comment: @Wei see my updated question.. Yes new size will also come but i want to check with theses sizes only  S,M,L

Answer (score 0):

If you group by product then in the `ORDER BY` clause all you need is:

```
ORDER BY SUM(stock = 0) > 0
```

The expression `stock = 0` evaluates to `1` if there is no stock available for one of the sizes 'S', 'M' or 'L', so in this case `SUM()` will return a positive number and `SUM(stock = 0) > 0` will evaluate to `1` sorting the product after the products for which there is no row with `stock = 0`:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM product_attributes
WHERE size in ('S', 'M', 'L')
GROUP BY product_id, product_name
ORDER BY SUM(stock = 0) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this is a `group by` with a filtering on the sizes that you want:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM product_attributes
WHERE size IN ('S', 'M', 'L')
GROUP BY product_id, product_name
```

Then you want an `ORDER BY`.  It is unclear if you really want:

```
ORDER BY SUM(stock > 0) = 3 DESC
```

or:

```
ORDER BY SUM(stock = 0) ASC
```

or:

```
ORDER BY SUM(stock <> 0) DESC
```

The first guarantees that all three sizes are there (assuming there are no duplicates) AND that all three have values greater than `0`in `stock`.

The second orders by the number of rows that are `0`.  So, those products with no `0`s in the `stock` column will be first and so on for the rest.

The third orders by the count of `stock` NOT being zero in a descending pattern.

The difference would be clear if you had data like this:

```
21      1            DEF         S      2
22      1            DEF         L      5
```

Presumably, there is no size `M` for `DEF`.  Do you want that in the result set at all?  Does it count as all being in stock?